# Google Chrome developer tools element properties analysis

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Can someone explain what the space colored in orange means?

Firstly, I considered it was margin spacing but than I saw that the margin actually equals zero.

[Screenshot](http://take.ms/uXx9C)  (Sorry, I can't yet post any pictures on Stackoverflow)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is still margin. Almost everywhere it is displayed correctly and Chrome itself says it is a margin. So I would say it is a margin with a rare bug in there.

Answer (score 0):

The item you have highlighted - `<p>` - has no margin or padding which is why it is showing as zero in the diagram at the bottom. The orange area is actually the area of the container div 'hist'. If you highlight the containing element using the same tool you will probably find that it has some `padding-right` which is causing the empty space (or rather, filling it with padding so the text can't enter it), or your `<p>` has a maximum width set which is causing it to have the empty space, or wrap before it reaches the edge.

Comment: It could also be to do with the column offset - without having access to it it's difficult to say for certain.